# Efficiently updating a common repository used by multiple other repositories

Tags: testing, microservices, continuous-integration, integration-tests

Suppose we have a project consisting of many microservices, all of which use a common library. The common library has been put into a separate git repository, and each microservice is also in its own individual git repository.

When the time comes to make a change to the common library, how should that be done? Because all of the microservices use it, it seems like it would be necessary to clone all the microservice repositories that were not cloned locally already, update each of them to point to the new version of the common library, publish locally the new version of the common library, and then run all of their tests. And then, in principle, this has to be done on the CI system as well, because otherwise there could be a subtle difference in the local environment that makes the change happen to build OK on the local environment, but not in CI!

If we don't do this, but simply do the lazy thing and update only the common library and the particular microservice we are working on at the moment, we run the risk that we accidentally break something in another microservice and that this only becomes apparent later when the dependency on the common library gets bumped in the latter microservice. If the common library were an open source project and the microservices depending on it were third party code, we could just say "tough luck - you fix it on your side, or raise a PR to fix it on our side. It's not our responsibility to babysit your repositories." But since they are our repositories, they *are* our responsibility - so we shouldn't really break them gratuitously with a poorly-thought-out change to the common library.

However, the approach of testing all common library changes everywhere that I have outlined is laborious - and doesn't scale particularly well, either. (Imagine if Google had their billions of lines of in-house code, not in a mono-repo but in this kind of setup - how would they be able to make safe  changes to shared libraries in a scalable way?)

What sorts of approaches can be used to better manage such updates and make the QA more efficient?

Comment: Is the common library in its own repo because it has value on its own or because it's shared between the services? Is there ever a case when the common library will change outside the context of what it provides to the services?

Comment: `it seems like it would be necessary to ...` -- Does the way you build your common library cause its external API to change each time you build it?  Surely not.

Comment: `Imagine if Google had their billions of lines of in-house code ...` -- Google indeed has this problem.  The Go programming language is one of the responses to that problem.  But you don't have Google's problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the external API of the shared library isn't _supposed_ to change every time we build it, no. But it might change _accidentally_ - e.g. due to a subtle change in behaviour which doesn't cause any of its own unit tests to fail.

Comment: And your integration tests are supposed to catch these subtle changes in behaviors?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.

Comment: Well, the solution could be as simple as, during the build, copying your shared DLL to those places where it is used, including the integration tests.  Git has a "shared library" option you should explore, if you're using Git.

Comment: Which is essentially the procedure you describe in your question.  I don't understand why that would be particularly onerous; *automate it.*

Comment: How long does it take to run your entire body of unit tests and integration tests for all of your microservices?

Comment: @DM In reality, it's both - it does have value on its own and is depended on by other teams' code as well. So that adds a second, slightly different type of risk to be considered - that we will accidentally break other teams' code due to not having good enough integration or unit test coverage. But for the purpose of this question, let's pretend that risk is negligible.

Comment: A libraries API is a contract and it shouldn't be changed unless you are releasing a new major version of the library, in which case projects that use it should be aware of these changes. Any problem related to internal changes or fixes should be picked up by unit and integration tests, and either be fixed or notified in release notes.

Comment: @Calabacin that's all very well in theory, but in practice a library's own tests don't always catch all problems.

Comment: @RobinGreen Libraries we create include an additional project that uses the library to show how it works. It includes tests as well, we call them "integration tests". That way we can always see our library working as intended, library users can see examples of proper use, and we can test that integrations are smooth. In our case most libraries used in Windows are made in c++ so we absolutely have to do this in order to test library integration with .net applications.

Answer (score 2):

In my company we solve this problem simply by uploading the shared libraries to Nexus. Here is how we do it:

1. Library has its own integration and release jobs.
2. When we create a new release of the library it is uploaded to Nexus with a new version number.
3. All applications that use this library can simply specify what version they need and download it automatically as part of your build process (using maven, gradle, nuget, shell script, etc.).
4. Each application can use a different version of the library, and they can upgrade at their own pace.

[Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product/repository-oss?topnav=true) is an 'artifact repository server', but you could use your own storage solution if you don't have one.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This approach works... until it doesn't. Consider the following corner case: a refactoring is done to the library, which is intended to be safe and only affect the internal implementation, not the API. Since no-one needs this refactoring, no-one upgrades to the new version of the library. Subsequently, an urgent requirement comes in and a change needs to be made to the library and all microservices updated to use the new version. Then the incompatibility/brokenness is discovered.

Comment: @RobinGreen you solve this using major and minor versions and proper documentation. Anyone upgrading to a new major release should expect potential incompatible changes. Also versions have a lifetime during which they should receive updates to urgent issues (i.e. bugs). If a project needs a new feature in my library and I make it, surely they'll understand they will need to use the latest version. In my opinion none of the problems you mention are related to our way of working, as they would all happen in any other methodology you apply.

Comment: Also it is common that a library fixes issues and bugs in their library, hence "only affecting internal implementation". Projects should get these fixes or at least be made aware of consequences of not doing it via release notes. I really cannot think of any such change that wouldn't be caught with proper unit and integration tests.